# Efficient way to load mass amounts of images in pygame?

Tags: python, image, pygame

This is the way I've been using to do it so far.

```
pygame.image.load("a.png")
pygame.image.load("b.png")
pygame.image.load("c.png")
```

However, if I have an animation with 60 images, how do I efficiently load all of that in?

Comment: You can combine a bunch of them into a "sprite sheet" —  which is a single file that contains many smaller images. See [Using Sprite Sheets in Pygame](https://ehmatthes.github.io/pcc_2e/beyond_pcc/pygame_sprite_sheets/).

Comment: What do you mean by efficiently? Is execution speed your worry or you just don't want to write 60 lines of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For performance reasons, you must load the files before the application loop.
One option is to load the image files and store the *Surfaces* in a dictionary:

```py
import os
folder = #image folder
```

```py
files = ['a.png', 'b.png', 'c.png']
images = {}
for filepath in files:
    path, filename = os.path.basename(filepath)
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(path)
    image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(folder, file path)).convent_ alpha()
    images[name] = image
```

In the application loop, you can access the images by subscription:

```py
image =  images['a']
```

Comment: bad_coder: If the image files are the only ones in the folder, hardcoding their names into a list in the script shouldn't be necessary — as would generally be a bad idea anyway, especially if there are a large number of them. The contents of the folder can be obtained with `os.listdir()` and `glob.glob()`.